# Optional Prefix part in Route

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a rather complex-route schema and I'm stuck.

**Routes that I wan't to match**

```
/books                  indexAction
/books/show             showAction
/books/authorname       indexAction
/books/authorname/show  showAction
```

**Current Setup**

**Routing.yml**

```
actions:
  resource: routing/actions.yml
  prefix: /books/{authorname}
  requirements:
      authorname: ".*"
  defaults:
      authorname: ''
```

**routing/actions.yml**

```
books_index:
    path:   ""
    defaults: { _controller:bookController:indexAction }

books_show:
    path:   "/show"
    defaults: { _controller:bookController:showAction }
```

This Setup currently matches only:

```
/books/                  indexAction
/books/show             showAction
/books/authorname       indexAction
/books/authorname/show  showAction
```

but not

```
/books
```

The reasons why I split those routes into two files is that in reality the actions contain much more routes, also there is other routing-categories then the actions.

I know I could define the **/books** route manually without a prefix but I want to avoid this as this schema will be used for many different modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `/book` prefix in any case.

One solution is to define separate entries in your `routing.yml` for that. One with `/books` prefix and the second with `/books/{authorname}`.

```
index:
  resource: routing/actions.yml
  prefix: /books

show:
  resource: routing/actions.yml
  prefix: /books/{authorname}
```

It's not so elegant, but in this case you can get rid of extra `requirements` section.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that did the job.